# Why does running a server make window unresponsive?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a button that opens another window and starts a server when pressed.

```
class GUI: #initializes main window and button

    def __init__(self): 

       self.mlobbybutton = tk.Button(self.createframe, text = "Make Lobby", bg = "Black", fg = "White", command = lambda: self.makelobby())
       self.mlobbybutton.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

    def makelobby(self): #hides main window and initializes new window

        self.master.withdraw()
        self.h = GUI2()

class GUI2(GUI): #packs new window and calls server to start

    def __init__(self):

        self.s = INITSERVER() #initializes server
        self.s.startChat() #starts the server

class INITSERVER(GUI2, Thread):

    def __init__(self): #initializes server attributes
        self.PORT = 5000
        self.SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
        self.ADDRESS = (self.SERVER, self.PORT)
        self.FORMAT = "utf-8"
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                        socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    
        self.server.bind(self.ADDRESS)

    def startChat(self): #starts the server

        print("server is working on " + self.SERVER)

        self.server.listen()

        while True:

            self.conn, self.addr = self.server.accept()
        
            self.name = self.conn.recv(1024).decode(self.FORMAT)

            self.conn.send('Connection successful!'.encode(self.FORMAT))

            print(f"active connections {threading.activeCount()-1}")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    g = GUI()
    tk.mainloop()
```

The code above makes the new window unresponsive if the server is **started**; if not, then the window is fine. No errors displayed in the terminal.

I need to know how to make new window responsive while the server is still running. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @N. Tanaka. Do u meant how to add usernames into listbox?

Comment: You need to run `startChat()` in a child thread. Study `threading` module.